# "By a month" Vs. "in a month"

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between these two sentence?

> He's sure that he'll speak French fluently **in a month**.

Vs.

> He's sure that he'll speak French fluently **by a month**.

Answer (score 2):

"by a month" is simply not idiomatic at all in English here.

**For time**, one does things or things are done **in a month, week, year, day, hour etc**. That is the period of time that will elapse.

**He beat the deadline by a month**.

There, **by a month is used to measure the number of months he won by.**

Some project has to be handed in in six months. The guy hands the project in in five months. He has beat the deadline ***by a month***.

For time that will elapse (go by) we use in: in a month.

To measure some amount of time in relation to a set time, we use by:

He beat me by ten minutes. They beat us (in the sailing race) by a month.

Comment: @Perplexed folks We use **by** to specify a time or deadline, as in **by tonight, by tomorrow evening, by the end of the week**.

Comment: @RonalsSole So both can be correct in context. Isn't it?

Comment: @Perplexedfolks Yes, we use **in** for a duration (a day, a week, a month, a year) and **by** for a (rough) point  in time (5pm, the end of the month etc)

Comment: @Perplexedfolks You mean to ask: Both can be correct in context, ***can't they***? Answer: No, ***by a month*** can never be right in this context in English. By a month: He beat the deadline by a month. [another meaning]

Comment: @LucianSava No, that is not right. Our contract can be terminated ***at a month's notice*** or with a month's notice.

Comment: @RonaldSole The OP is repeating the same question again. The answer is no. They are not both idiomatic ***for what the OP wants to say***.

Answer (score 1):

"In a month" is correct. It means that it will take 1 month by the time he'll speak fluent French. "By" is used to indicate the end point of an event. For example, you can say "He'll speak fluent French by February". February is the deadline by which the activity will be completed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+^1), but I really don't understand what's the difference between "in" and "by" in these sentence. You explained that "by" indicates end point of an event. For example "He'll be there in a month" = He'll be there *after* one month from now. It is the same as "by a month". Isn't it?

Comment: @Perplexedfolks it's not the same, because "a month" is a *span* of time, and "by" (in this context) takes a *point* in time.  Hence you can say "by February" (because "February" is acting as shorthand for "the start of February", which is a point in time), but not "by a month" (because "a month" isn't a point, but a distance).

Comment: @Perplexedfolks In terms of a specific point in time and the use of *by*, you would say *by* ***next*** *month*. (Note the lack of *a*.) Further, it would *not* be natural to say ***in*** *next month*.

Comment: @Perplexedfolks I will finish in ten minutes. Same thing. When you are referring to an amount of time, use in: to start in ten minutes, to start in two years. For deadlines, by six o'clock, by 2021.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is that one of those two sentences is grammatical, and the other is not.

> "He's sure that he'll speak French fluently **in a month**"

is correct.  It is equivalent to "He's sure that he'll speak French fluently within a month", or "He's sure that before a month has passed, he'll speak French fluently".  In this context, "[with]in [some amount of time]" means "before [that much time] has elapsed".

> "He's sure that he'll speak French fluently **by a month**"

is not grammatical, because in this context "by [something]" means "before [something] has *happened*". "In" needs a *span* - a *length* of time, which might begin now, or at some other point already established by context ("once he starts the course, he's sure that he'll speak French fluently in a month" would mean the month started when the course did, at some point in the future, rather than right now).

"**By**" needs an **point** in time: "a month" isn't a point, but "next month" could be (in this context it would be taken to mean "the **start** of next month").  Hence you might say "he's sure that he'll speak French fluently by summer", because "[the start of] summer" is a point.  So is "dinner", though expecting someone to gain fluency between now and dinner is probably unreasonable.  You can use "by the time [something happens]" in a similar way, so you could say "by the time a month is up", where "the time a month is up" means the point in time at which one complete month has passed.

Comment: Or you could say "I'm sure she'll be fluent by dinner time" or "I'm sure he'll be fluent by Summer." (which is probably a little more realistic ;) )

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks; I was blanking on good events to use as examples but those are much better and I shall edit accordingly.

Comment: "By" does not "need an event". "By" needs a deadline for doing something i.e. a date, a time, specified or implied. He will be home by dinnertime. "Can you finish this job by 3:00 o'clock?"

Comment: @Lambie you are correct; "event" is not quite the right word, but I was focusing on distinguishing *points in* time from *spans of* time, and when I wrote the answer I felt the phrasing I've used in this comment might be confusing. I don't remember why I thought that, only that I did.

Comment: @Darael why not to use "a point of time" instead of an "event"?

Comment: @Perplexedfolks I'm not entirely sure what past-me was thinking, but at a guess, I was trying to avoid using the word "time" so as to make the distinction between a point and a span clearer.  Clearly it didn't have that effect, though.  The last couple of comments came in while I was in bed, but I have now edited my answer to talk about points in time.